# Difference between setting to a variable and setting the state and setting the state directly in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can Anyone explain me the difference between both of these implementations.
The first implementation doesn't work as expected for me

```
//Setting state in constructor through a variable
this.list;
this.state = {
   Items: list
};
//Implementation 1
var temp = "result after logic";
this.setState({
   Items: temp
});
//Implementation 2
var temp = "result after logic";
this.list = temp;
this.setState({
   Items: this.list
});
```

Comment: "*The first implementation doesn't work as expected for me*". Could you clarify what do you expect?

Comment: As far as I understand you have shown three implementations

Comment: I was creating a CRUD based app , on the delete operation I filter the list array and remove the object which needs to be deleted , I store the result of filter in a new array and did this.setState({Item:temp}), but on the next render the item returned , I did the second implementation and it worked. I wanted to know the difference between three

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri  that starting one is just setting the state in the constructor . I am sorry the setState method is called wrong it should be setState({}) . Should i provide a link of the implementation in codeSandbox?

Comment: That's odd, there shouldn't be a difference, since this.list is just another variable with context this. A link could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Implementation 1:**
This will cause an error due to the missing declaration of list. *this.state =* will set your state to literally just *Items: list*, discarding all other data stored in state. It's basically for initialization.

**Implementation 2:**

Your state of "Items" is now "result after logic" and your Component will rerender.

**Implementation 3:**

1. this.list has the value "result after logic". It is now globally available within your component.
2. Your state of "Items" is now "result after logic" and your Component will rerender.

The difference is basically, that this.list can be accessed anywhere, just like state does. However, if you change the value of this.list, it will not cause your component to rerender. So you could do something like this:

```
methodA(){
  var temp = "result after logic";
  this.list = temp;
  methodB();
}

methodB(){
  this.setState = {
    Items: this.list
  };
}
```

this.list will be known, even though you defined it in methodA (Implementation 3).

In the other case (Implementation 2), you couldn't do that, because var temp will be known only in methodA, not methodB, unless you pass it as argument.

Comment: so if i initialize state through a variable (list in this case) I have to put the result after logic in this.list variable and then set the State?.

Comment: No, you have to first get the value you want to store / display and then call setState with that value to see the result.
You don't need to use this.list at all, unless you want the value you store in this.list somewhere else (where you otherwise may not have access to it) and don't want you component to render again.

Comment: So you call this.state = {foo: 'bar'}; to initialize in the constructor. Later on you call this.setState({foo: 'something else'}) to cause your view to update.

Comment: Thanks , I am getting it now , will run some code examples to understand , thanks cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You use `this.state = { clicked: false }` in constructor to describe initial state of you component. Later on - for example in `onClick` handler you use `this.setState({ clicked: false })` to change state of your component - but there is a one catch - it is async function.

You may read about it in docs - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate and there is also a nice article about it - https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b .

So just to summarize:

- `this.state = Object` -> use it in constructor to describe initial
  state of component - use it only in constructor
- `this.setState(Object)` -> use it everywhere outside constructor -
  remember it is async!